# Creating new Solr index when using Solr without Search API

Tags: search

I've previously worked with Solr with the Search API module, but currently I'm working on a client project which is hosted at Acquia, and since they [seem to discourage using Search API](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-search/search-api) in favor of the non-Search API Solr modules, I'm trying to see if I can accomplish my task without Search API.

I've hit a wall, however, in that I want to add a new "index," to use the Search API terminology. The site already has a single index for general site search, but I want to add one that will only index content of one type and have particular facets and such. With Search API it's very easy to create a new index, but I haven't yet been able to figure it out without it, and haven't been able to find an answer via search engine - maybe "index" isn't the terminology I need to use here…?

Comment: So, they encourage using the [Apache Solr Search Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module... any reason you can't use that?

Comment: It's what I'll end up doing if I can't find another way to do this, but I'm trying to avoid it first, both because Acquia discourages it and because I'd have to rebuild the current index settings using Search API (though doing that would probably have been faster than trying to find this answer at this point).

Comment: I can only see the beginning of that article but it appears to me that they **discourage Search API** and **encourage the apache solr module**.  Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. Let me try again. The site *is* using the Apache Solr Search Integration module currently, and not Search API. But I will switch to using Search API if it turns out to be impossible to use more than one index without it.

Comment: Ahh right... would it suit your purposes to create a second search environment in solr (another collection)?

Comment: Maybe that's what I'm trying to do and I'm just not finding out how because I'm using Search API terminology instead of Solr terminology. How would I go about that? I'm not finding a "new environment" or similar button in the UI.

Comment: `admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings` and click Add search environment... but this does require you to set up another collection in solr too.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, which I will confess is still a possibility, it seems to require instantiating an entirely new Solr instance. I give up; Search API it is.

Comment: No you can have multiple 'collections' within the same Solr instance. It is an entirely new set of files but it uses the same daemon